# Values from .max() as new dataframe in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have some 10Hz GPS data from which I have added some rolling .sum() columns e.g below

```
resultsQ1['5s']=resultsQ1['OdChange'].rolling(window=50,axis=0).sum()
```

I have then identified the largest value in the new column while grouping from another column e.g below

```
combinedQ15s = resultsQ1.groupby('Stat5s')['5s'].max()/5
```

What I want to do now is to return the 50 values that make up the .max() value as a new df

Is this possible?

Comment: _What I want to do now is to return the values that make up the .max() value as a new df_ I'm not sure I understand what you mean, can you expand on that?

Comment: I can try. I am new to all this.
within my large dataset I have a column that is providing the Sum of 50 values from another column on a rolling 50 window.
I then have a formula to identify the Max of that column
I now want a new df that is presenting the 50 values that make up the above Max so I can extract them to a csv

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
res=resultsQ1.merge(resultsQ1.groupby('Stat5s')['5s'].max(), right_index=True, left_on="Stat5s", suffixes=["", "_max"])

res=res.loc[res["5s_max"]==res["5s"]]

#so you can differentiate the final result from records that make it up:
res["cat"]="total"+res.assign(dummy=1)["dummy"].cumsum().map(str)
res2=res.copy()
for el in res.index:
    order=list(df.index).index(el)
    dftemp=resultsQ1.iloc[order-49:order].copy()
    dftemp["cat"]=res.loc[el, "cat"].replace("total", "makeup")
    res2=res2.append(dftemp, ignore_index=True, sort=True)
```

(`res2` is your output)
Some reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: Thanks for that but from what I can see that is just returning where the results occur within the dataframe. Maybe my explanation was poor. I want a new df with the 50 values that make up the .max() value

Comment: Not sure, if I understand, what 50 values, and in what sense they "make up" the max?

Comment: resultsQ1['5s']=resultsQ1['OdChange'].rolling(window=50,axis=0).sum() is providing the sum of 50 values. The max value finds the largest value in that new column however on top of that I also want to identify the 50 values into a new df

Comment: But you want to aggregate them in list? How do you want to see this 50 records window?

Comment: I would like to be able to print the 50 records to an excel file.

Comment: I tweaked my answer- now you should get as ```res2``` the ```max``` row with ```cat``` = ```totalN``` where ```N``` is just an internal iterator, and the respective 49 previous rows (which in addition to the row itself makeup the rolling window of 50) as ```makeupN```.